# How to import a variable value into a csv file via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, input

This is my code

```
userName = int(input("What username do you need?"))
value = pd.read_csv(UserInfos, usecols=['Username'])
userN_value = value.get(int(userName))
print(value['Username'][userN_value])
```

As you can see I am using `userN` as the argument to find a certain value in the .csv file where I store all the usernames and all the passwords. The problem is that I'm not able to find any information about using variables as pandas arguments, and the compiler doesn't say anything, it just says that there's a problem with the line.
So, does anybody know how to use it? Or if I have to do anything manually.

Comment: I think you should re-think security if you have passwords in plain text but you need `.loc` or plain filtering : `df.loc[df['Username'] == userN_value]` , `df[df['Username'] == userN_value]`

Comment: I tried both `.loc` and `df[df['username']]` yet it doesn't work

Comment: then the input doesn't match, you sure its an integer? `print(df.dtypes)`

Comment: it doesn't return the value, for some reason it returns an error instead of returning the dtype

Comment: If your code returns some error, you should post the full stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For looking up a value in pandas, the .get syntax you have does not work for me.  You can filter the dataframe to the row(s) that == user value, see this toy example:

```
userName = '1'
value = pd.DataFrame({'Username': [1, 2, 3]})
df_user = value.loc[value['Username'] == int(userName)]
print(df_user['Username'].tolist()[0])
# 1

userN_value = value.get(int(userName))
print(userN_value)
# None
```